# Why does Parallel.For execute the WinForms message pump, and how to prevent it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to speed up a lengthy (a few ms) operation* using `Parallel.For`, but I'm getting Paint events all over my WinForms application before the method has returned - suggesting it somehow triggers a message pump. The overall redraw, however, leads to accessing data in an inconsistent state, producing erratic errors and exceptions. I need to assure that `Parallel.For`, while blocking, doesn't trigger UI code.

My research on this so far has been inconclusive and pointed me roughly to things like synchronization contexts and `TaskScheduler` implementations, but I have yet to make sense of it all.

If someone could help me along the way by clearing some things up, that would very much be appreciated.

1. What is the chain of events that leads to `Parallel.For` triggering WinForms message pump?
2. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening entirely?
3. Alternatively, is there any way to tell if a UI event handler is called from the regular message pump, or the "busy" message pump as triggered by `Parallel.For`?

---

*Edit:* * Some context: The above few ms operation is part of a game engine loop, where 16 ms are available for a full update - hence the attribute "lengthy". The context of this problem is executing a game engine core inside its editor, which is a WinForms application. `Parallel.For` happens during the internal engine update.

Comment: Some more research on this after evaluating the answers so far: https://github.com/AdamsLair/duality/issues/295

Answer (score 4):

This comes from the CLR, it implements the contract that an STA thread (aka UI thread) is never allowed to block on a synchronization object.  Like Parallel.For() does.  It pumps to ensure that no deadlock can occur.

This gets Paint events to fire, and some others, the exact message filtering is a well-kept secret.  It is pretty similar to DoEvents() but the stuff that is likely to cause re-entrancy bugs blocked.  Like user input.

But clearly you have a DoEvents() style bug in spades, re-entrancy is forever a nasty bug generator.  I suspect you'll need to just set a *bool* flag to ensure that the Paint event skips an update, simplest workaround.  Changing the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() method in Program.cs to [MTAThread] is also a simple fix, but is quite risky if you also have normal UI.  Favor the `private bool ReadyToPaint;` approach, it is simplest to reason through.

You should however investigate exactly why Winforms thinks that Paint is needed, it shouldn't since you are in control over the Invalidate() call in a game loop.  It *may* fire because of user interactions, like min/max/restoring the window but that should be rare.  Non-zero odds that there's another bug hidden under the floor mat.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! The behavior may very well be caused by user interaction, as it usually happens in editor mode, where an embedded game view allows to edit and interact with the scene. The game loop isn't running in this case, but redrawing and updating is done on-demand - which can trigger arbitrary core game code that unfortunately expects to remain in full control until it finished. The bool solution probably won't cut it in this case.

Anyway - I'll investigate some more on possible alternatives :)

Comment: Meh, that bool flag can still work just fine.  Maybe you should name it *NotReadyToPaint* for clarity, you always know when you are not because you are busy updating stuff that gets used in the Paint event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know when I'm not ready, as there is no clear update-render cycle in an editor context. If the user interacts with an arbitrary editor UI element, it could, theoretically, invoke core engine code in order to update game data as requested by the user. This update may or may not use `Parallel.For`, which then triggers a paint event in the middle of a data update. How would I know when to reject this event if I don't know how it was triggered? There is no "invalidation loop" for the engine core that represents the only valid time to redraw the game view.

Comment: You know with 100% confidence that you are not ready just before you call Parallel.For().  So set NotReadyToPaint = true before it and back to false after it.  Re-entrancy problem solved.

Comment: The game engine code that uses `Parallel.For` is part of a core library that may or may not be executed in an editor or WinForms environment, so there is no knowledge about the concepts required to solve this problem. It get's worse when considering that the engine is plugin-based, so there's platform- and environment-agnostic user code that could use `Parallel.For`. Since the root of the problem is part of the WinForms context, it would be preferable if the solution could be part of the same context, rather than being that "invasive" to core and user code.

Comment: Of course I could write a wrapper class for `Parallel` that has internal knowledge about this, which it shares with the editor, should it be present, but _if_ there was a way to avoid that, I'd very much prefer it.

Answer (score 3):

As already explained, `Parallel.For` itself does not execute the WinForms message pump, but the CLR implementation of `Wait` which is called by the necessary thread synchronization primitives is causing the behavior.

Luckily that implementation can be overridden by installing a custom `SynhronizationContext` because all CLR waits actually call [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.wait(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the current (i.e. associated with the current thread) synchronization context.

The idea is to call `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` API which has no such side effects. I can't say whether it is safe or not, CLR designers have their reasons, but from the other side, they have to handle many different scenarios which may not apply to your case, so at least it's worth trying.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public static void Install()
    {
        var currentContext = Current;
        if (currentContext is CustomSynchronizationContext) return;
        WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false;
        SetSynchronizationContext(new CustomSynchronizationContext(currentContext));
    }

    public static void Uninstall()
    {
        var currentContext = Current as CustomSynchronizationContext;
        if (currentContext == null) return;
        SetSynchronizationContext(currentContext.baseContext);
    }

    private WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext baseContext;

    private CustomSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext currentContext)
    {
        baseContext = currentContext as WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext  ?? new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
        SetWaitNotificationRequired();
    }

    public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy() { return this; }
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) { baseContext.Post(d, state); }
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) { baseContext.Send(d, state); }
    public override void OperationStarted() { baseContext.OperationStarted(); }
    public override void OperationCompleted() { baseContext.OperationCompleted(); }

    public override int Wait(IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int result = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(waitHandles.Length, waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout, false);
        if (result == -1) throw new Win32Exception();
        return result;
    }

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(int nCount, IntPtr[] pHandles, bool bWaitAll, int dwMilliseconds, bool bAlertable);
}
```

In order to activate it, just add the following line before your `Application.Run(...)` call:

```
CustomSynchronizationContext.Install();
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a try :)

Comment: How do I implement this in VB.NET? There is no Application.Run() call in VB.NET projects...

Answer (score 0):

Hans explained it in. So what should you do? The easiest path would be to have one `volatile bool` flag that says if data are consistent and is okay to use them to paint.

Better, but more complicated, solution would be to replace `Parallel.For` with your own [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and send simple task to the pool. Main GUI thread would then stay responsive to user input.

Also, those simple task must not change the GUI directly, but just manipulate the data. Game GUI must be changed only in `OnPaint`.

Answer (score 0):

Hans explained it. So what should you do? Don't run that loop on the UI thread. Run it on a background thread, for example:

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.For(...));
```

Blocking on the UI thread is not a good idea in general. Not sure how relevant that is to a game engine loop design but this fixes the reentrancy problems.

Comment: `Parallel.For` is called as part of the game engine code, which is in a distinct library that may or may not be invoked by a WinForms application. Consequently, there is no concept of "blocking the UI" or not, so this is unfortunately not an option. It's also not really a concern, as a hard requirement of the game engine is to finish all update calculations of a frame within around 16 ms to remain interactive at all times.

Comment: Maybe you can call the library using Task.Run.