# How to prevent Parallel.For to unlock the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, task-parallel-library

Yes, if you call do a Parallel.For from main thread of a WinForms application you'll see that the message pump starts processing `WM_` messages while the Parallel.For is crunching.

Is there a way to avoid this? I mean, to do the work in parallel and freeze the UI completely?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to freeze the ui?

Comment: See info about Parallel.For and CLR's implementation of Wait here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535580/why-does-parallel-for-execute-the-winforms-message-pump-and-how-to-prevent-it

Comment: TL;DR: Do whatever the Parallel.For would have done in another thread.

Comment: @Wyck: I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253204/261010)  but does not help...

Comment: I can't reproduce it. `Parallel.For` freezes my UI the same way it is frozen by `Thread.Sleep(10000)` for example.